# How to find a certain string and then take that string and search it in other cell in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I find a particular String and then copy that string, search for it in a different cell then if I find the correct string on the other cell, go to the corresponding cell and copy and paste it into another cell? I keep on getting an error while I am using Instr then another Instr. Any suggestion please anyone. If you see the attached then basically what i am trying to do is First find H which is in michale, then copy michale and search for it in A column, once i find it in A column i go to corresponding column and copy Pick-me* paste it any where in sheet.

```
     Sub ex_find()

       Dim ws As Worksheet, m As String, lastrow As Long
          Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
           lastrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
              For i = 2 To lastrow
                m = ws.Cells(i, 5)
                  If InStr(ws.Cells(i, 5), "h") > 0 Then
                    InStr(ws.Cells(i, 1), "m") = 0

                  End If

             Next 
    End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question confuses me a little.  I think you want to search for an "h" in values of column "F" and when found search column "A" for the value of found cell in column "F".  Then you want to do something with a "corresponding cell"

```
Sub ex_find()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, m As String, lastrow As Long, myArray() As Variant
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    lastrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If InStr(1, ws.Range("F" & i).Value, "h") <> 0 Then
            With ws.Range("a1:a" & lastrow)
                Set c = .Find(ws.Range("F" & i).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    'firstAddress = c.Address
                    'Do
                    'This is where you put your code to change "corresponding cell"



                    'Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 

                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for he confusion. After i find the instr then i want to take that instr and search it in another cell if you look into attached file, you will understand. If i find the first string in cell 5, then i will search it on cell 1 and if i find the match then i will go to corresponding cell which is 2 and copy pick me and paste it into any empty cell.

Comment: Sorry but I don't download pics or files.  And I'm still a little confused on several things.  Do you want to find the first instance of "h" in column F, then find that same value in column A, and then do something with Column B of that same row?

Comment: no i am not telling you to download it, its there you can see it below my code. So i am looping through column F, which contain values(Sam, Blue, Michacle)etc. If i find h which is michacle, i like to take Michacle and search it in Column A. If i find Michacle in column A then go to corresponding Column B and take the value and paste it in another Cell.

Comment: Yes, my computer is blocked for images because they can carry hacked viruses.  But I changed my answer above.  It will find all instances of "h" in column "F", search for that entire value in column "A", and allow you to do whatever you need to a "corresponding cell."  It is set up to find all instances of that value in column "A" also.  You can easily change that to the first instance of either column "F" or Column "A".

Comment: I had to make one change to the answer again

Comment: Mugglins Quick question what is  firstAddress = c.Address means and Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress . Sorry if i am asking you too much, i just don't want to copy and paste the code, i also want to understand too. So i can learn it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx  The variable firstAddress is the first instance in column "A" where the value from Column "F" is found.  The loop continues through column "A" until it finds all instances of that value, in case there is more than one "Michael" in column "A" for example.  It will find all of them.  The FirstAddress is necessary to make the loop stop when it finds that again.

Comment: oh ok so once i find the first address it will stop right cause i want it to exit loop soon as it's find the first michacle. Should i put exit loop in there after
Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress

Comment: No.  But I changed the answer again to comment out the loop.  Do you want to stop after it finds the first word with an "h" in Column "F" also?  If so just put "Exit For" after your code that changes the corresponding cell.

Comment: never mind code is working fine, the way it is. Thanks I am just confuse about the last line Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress

Comment: another quick question. Did you define c as string or range. cause i did it both and getting an error but if i don't define it then i do't get an error. What's the trick here

Comment: Dim c as object